# Unable to delete a file after reading it

Tags: java, jsp, file-io

I'm serving a file from the file system [dynamically with a jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114488/how-to-serve-a-file-with-jsp)

Here's my code:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*"
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream responseOut = null;
    File  file  = new File(request.getAttribute("fileToServe"));
    try{
        in = new FileInputStream(file);
        responseOut = response.getOutputStream();
        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            responseOut.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
    }finally{
         if( responseOut != null ) try {
            responseOut.close();
         } catch( IOException ioe ){}

        if( in != null ) try {
            in.close();
         } catch( IOException ioe ){}
    }
    file.delete();
%>
```

The problem I'm facing is, the file is delete only the first time the code is run, which is after the server restart. Subsequent calls doesn't delete the file.

I used ProcessExplorer to track this and and yeap, the Java VM is holding that file, I don't really know why is this happening.

We will run on Windows OS, always, is there a work around for this?

I've found a number of resources on the internet about this, but I can't figure out from them how to solve this problem.

Comment: Does the code enter the catch (IOException ioe) block when you call in.close()?

Comment: Don't catch exceptions you can't handle and then just discard them. Let them propagate to the caller or as a minimum, log them.

Comment: @Eric and Mark: It doesn't enter it it. Actually I didn't have the `try/finally` section and I got no exception before that. I've added the `try` only to use the `finally`. I'm adding throw new `RuntimeException( ioe )` in the catch block but nothing happens.

Comment: @cletus: Mhh I haven't check that part. Is a "strange" "engine" ( which I love/hate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098145/sort-months-with-strings-algorithm/2098334#2098334 )  I'm going to look at that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What creates the file? I only see reading then deleting it in that code.

Things to watch out for:

- Reading a file requires read permissions from the file but deleting the file requires write permission from the *directory*; and
- Make sure you `close()` any files you create. If you don't you might lose data or it may take time to flush an implicit close.

Lastly, using an attribute like `fileToServe` that comes from the user is really dangerous. I'm hoping you're sanitizing that elsewhere. You should ensure that only allowed files are served this way.

Comment: @cletus: it comes internally.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've checked, after [cletus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18393/cletus) comment, the place where this file is being created. The `close` method on the stream that wrote the file was missing.

Mystery solved

cletus, please add your answer so I can accept it