# Sorting month names

Tags: java

I want to sort month names. I have tried the following:

```
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class SortingMonth {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SortedSet<String> monthSet = new TreeSet<String>();
        monthSet.add("Feb");
        monthSet.add("Jan");
        monthSet.add("Mar");
        monthSet.add("Dec");
        monthSet.add("Aug");

        for(String value:monthSet){
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Aug
Dec
Feb
Jan
Mar
```

**But I want the output in this order:**

```
Jan
Feb
Mar
Aug
Dec
```

Comment: there are only 12 of them, so you can hard code the order

Comment: This is because SortedSet does not know that Jan is January.

Comment: Why do you need it to be a set of month *names*? It would normally be better to have the month *numbers*, and then translate them into names when you need to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098145/sort-months-with-strings-algorithm

Comment: I can not hard code, since every time I used to get the values in differnt order dynamically, but I have to order pass in the order...

Comment: Even easier: create a `SortedSet<Date>`, where each date contains the same date and year but different month, then use a `SimpleDateFormat("MMM")` and parse each `Date`.

Comment: Other option may be using a `Set<String>` backed by a `LinkedHashSet<String>` and it will maintain the order the elements were inserted.

Comment: @Luigi SortedSet<Date> worked fine, what is this other option can u explain little clear ?

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try different way as following. [Best efficient way to sort Months and Year in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274098/best-efficient-way-to-sort-months-and-year-in-java)

```
List<String> abc = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Date> xyz = new ArrayList<Date>();

    abc.add("JAN-2010");
    abc.add("JAN-2011");
    abc.add("APR-2013");
    abc.add("NOV-2009");

    try {

        for (String abc1 : abc) {

            Date date;

            date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
                    .parse(abc1);
            xyz.add(date);

        }

        Collections.sort(xyz, new Comparator<Date>() {

            public int compare(Date arg0, Date arg1) {
                // return arg0.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
                return arg0.compareTo(arg1);
            }
        });

        for (Date date1 : xyz) {
            System.out.println("Sorted : " + date1);
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution friend :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a comparator in your `TreeSet` like this:

```
SortedSet<String> monthSet = new TreeSet<String>(new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM", Locale.US );
            return fmt.parse(o1).compareTo(fmt.parse(o2));
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    }
});
```

That is not very efficient but as close to your example code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not tell the `TreeSet` which ordering you want, it will use standard string ordering (alphabetic).

Use the constructor that takes a `Comparator<String>` and create an instance that sorts the values as you wish.

Comment: Oh, and most of the comments to your question are insightful... my answer is only useful if you stick to use that structure, and because it helps you understand what is happenning.

Comment: @nikpon it is hard to understand what do you mean.

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOTB way to achieve this. You would need to hardcore somewhere (be it in comparator or in some custom utility that might use month to handle this) the order of months

Comment: Hi using  Set<Date> and SimpleDateFormat("MMM") I got the expected output...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what else you'd like to do with the months, perhaps creating an enum type for them would be worthwhile. See here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 0):

If you make Month into an enum, this is very easy:

```
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

class SortingMonth {

  enum Month {
    Jan(1, "January"),
    Feb(2, "February"),
    Mar(3, "March"),
    //..
    Aug(8, "August"),
    //...
    Dec(12, "December");
    int id;
    String text;
    Month(int id, String text) {
      this.id = id;
      this.text = text;
    }
    public String text() {
      return text;
    }
    public int id() {
      return id;
    }
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SortedSet<Month> monthSet = new TreeSet<Month>();
      monthSet.add(Month.Feb);
      monthSet.add(Month.Jan);
      monthSet.add(Month.Mar);
      monthSet.add(Month.Dec);
      monthSet.add(Month.Aug);

      for(Month value:monthSet){
          System.out.println(value);
      }

  }

}
```

Comment: In this case, you don't even need the enum constructors and member functions but if you wanted to print the full month you could do: `println(value.text())`

Answer (score -1):

If you need a `Set<String>` with the names of the months and *sorted*, you may use a `LinkedHashSet<String>`. From [its javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) (emphasis mine):

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is **the order in which elements were inserted into the set** (insertion-order).

So, just do this:

```
Set<String> months = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
months.add("Jan");
months.add("Feb");
months.add("Aug");
months.add("Dec");
System.out.println(months);
```

Output:

```
[Jan, Feb, Aug, Dec]
```

Comment: LinkedHashSet just gives the order of the same insertion order right ? Here my requirement is what ever the order may be But I want in the month order......

Comment: Set<String> months = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
months.add("Feb");
months.add("Aug");
months.add("Dec");
months.add("Jan");                                         System.out.println(months);                                                Will Give Wrong results.

Comment: @ParthasarathyB that's because you're using the `LinkedHashSet` in the wrong way... Did you at least read my proposed example about **how to use it**?

Comment: @Luiggi, your answer for this particular post doesnot solve my problem.

Comment: @ParthasarathyB if you post which specific problem you have, then you would get better help.